# Changing attribute not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made the following example to describe my problem:

```js
$("tr > td > #arm").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().children("#arm").prop("disabled", true);
  $(this).parent().children("#disarm").prop("disabled", false);
});

$("tr > td > #disarm").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().children("#arm").prop("disabled", false);
  $(this).parent().children("#disarm").prop("disabled", true);;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="arm" disabled>Arm</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="disarm">Disarm</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
</script>
```

I have the above `table` with one `row` that contains 2 `cells` and a `button` in each `cell`. One of them is `disabled` so I made a script  where when I press the second `button` it should enable the first one and disable the one which was clicked.

Disabling the `button` that was clicked work as I expected but I don't know why it doesn't enable the other `button`.

Comment: `id` must be unique across the entire page. If you have more than one row in your real code, this will be a problem. Use `class` or `name` instead.

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique, so when you're working with them, there's no need to use traversal functions. Try selecting them directly.

Comment: If you are clicking on the button, why are you selecting its parent and than reselecting the button you just clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **not** selecting the right element. Your code is

```
$(this).parent().children("#disarm")
```

where `$(this)` is the *#arm* element, then `parent()` is the *td cell*.

So basically you're searching for a children element (*#disarm*) of that cell, that's why he can't find it

Try with this instead

```
$("tr > td > #arm").on("click", function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).closest("tr").find("#disarm").prop("disabled", false);
});

$("tr > td > #disarm").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("#arm").prop("disabled", false);
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Here it is a [WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hhmnrsrL/) of your code :)

Comment: I've made the changes with your code and works, It's pretty strange because I tested first with two parent() ( this way I was selecting the row ) and then selecting with children the buttons.

Comment: @PavelMarian maybe you changed HTML structure? that's why i **never** use `parent()` or `children()`etc.. 'cause changing HTML will compromise your js code

Comment: I am only changing some attributes, there are no big changes.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `prev` and `next`

```
$("tr > td > #arm").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().children("#arm").prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).parent().next().children("#disarm").prop("disabled", false);
});
$("tr > td > #disarm").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().prev().children("#arm").prop("disabled", false);
    $(this).parent().children("#disarm").prop("disabled", true);;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hfr33exa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to totatlly remove disable attribute from element. As far as I know not all browsers correctly works with disable="false"

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class and then use prop function as below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="arm" disabled class="test">Arm</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="disarm" class="test">Disarm</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script>
        $('.test').click(function(){
            $(".test").prop('disabled', function () {
   return ! $(this).prop('disabled');
});
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xjo7knjs/)**

**description**: I have added a class test to all the buttons and then I used the prop function. So the button on which click event occurs is disabled and rest all are enabled

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem. Use removeAttr to remove disabled to the element.

```
           <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="arm" disabled>Arm</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="disarm">Disarm</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script>
            $("tr > td > #arm").on("click", function() {
                $("#arm").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#disarm").removeAttr("disabled");
            });

            $("tr > td > #disarm").on("click", function() {
               $("#arm").removeAttr("disabled");
               $("#disarm").prop("disabled", true);;
            }); 
        </script>
```

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdyar7p3/) of a working example

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to select the parent when you click on the button.

```
$(this).parent().children("#arm").prop("disabled", true);
```

should just be

```
$(this).prop("disabled", false);
```

Now when you are trying to pick the other element you do this.

- You pick the parent of the button
- You look for the other button inside of that element.

The problem is the button is in a sibling of the parent. But there is no need to select the parents when you have the id. Just select it by its id to start, it will be faster.

```js
$("table tbody").on("click", "button", function() {
  var btn = $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  var  opposite = btn.attr("id") === "disarm" ? "#arm" : "#disarm";
  $(opposite).prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="arm" disabled>Arm</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="disarm">Disarm</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```